# Android Click after pointer stops moving

Tags: android, accessibility

I want to react when the pointer stops moving on an Android tablet/phone. I have connected a mouse to the phone and the automatic click works fine. I am using Lineage 7.1.2 on a Moto-G to have root access to the device Code is Java. Under "Settings->Accessibility->Click after pointer stops moving" I can set the delay before a click is executed and this works also fine with the mouse.

I have read the docs from [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) but it is not clear to get this kind of information.

So it is possible to get the timer when Android starts counting the interval, when the interval ends or gets aborted.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this your app? do you have the code for it? or you want to make something to work on all apps?

Comment: It's my app which sould add graphical feedback for the start of the timer which the android system starts. Then the click happens inside my app.

Comment: Currently i have no app which adds the feedback. Before i do the graphical stuff i want to check if its possible to get the information from the system.

Comment: you can try and see if there is a broadcast event that is fired.